# Microsoft's secure replacement for std::reverse_copy?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I have the following code:

```
Integer::Integer(const byte *encodedInteger, size_t byteCount, Signedness s, ByteOrder o)
{
    if(o == LITTLE_ENDIAN_ORDER)
    {
        SecByteBlock block(byteCount);
        std::reverse_copy(encodedInteger, encodedInteger+byteCount, block.begin());

        Decode(block.begin(), block.size(), s);
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm catching a [C4996 warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcz0bys.aspx) on the `std::reverse_copy`:

```
1>c:\Program Files\...\VC\include\algorithm(2184): warning C4996: 'std::_Reverse_copy': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
1>          c:\...\VC\include\algorithm(2168) : see declaration of 'std::_Reverse_copy'
1>          integer.cpp(2898) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::reverse_copy<const byte*,unsigned char*>(_BidIt,_BidIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=unsigned char *,
1>              _BidIt=const byte *
1>          ]
```

I'm happy to provide the destination buffer size or the last destination element to comply with best practices on Microsoft platforms.

***`byteCount`*** is a parameter (and *not* a compile time constant), so I *cannot* call the overload with the destination buffer size (***`count`*** template parameter below):

```
std::reverse_copy<byte*, byte*, count>(...);
```

I also naively tried adding the destination buffer size and last element, but they resulted in compile errors *"expects 3 arguments - 4 provided"*:

```
std::reverse_copy(encodedInteger, encodedInteger+byteCount, block.begin(), block.begin()+block.size());
```

What is Microsoft's secure replacement for std::reverse_copy that allows me to specify the destination buffer size?

---

Here are the overloads Microsoft provides from `<algorithm>`:

```
template<class _BidIt,
    class _OutIt> inline
_SCL_INSECURE_DEPRECATE
    _OutIt _Reverse_copy(_BidIt _First, _BidIt _Last,
        _OutIt _Dest,
        _STD tr1::false_type)
    {   // copy reversing elements in [_First, _Last), unchecked dest
    return (_Reverse_copy(_First, _Last,
        _Dest, _Iter_cat(_First), _Iter_cat(_Dest)));
    }

template<class _BidIt,
    class _OutIt> inline
    _OutIt reverse_copy(_BidIt _First, _BidIt _Last,
        _OutIt _Dest)
    {   // copy reversing elements in [_First, _Last)
    _DEBUG_RANGE(_First, _Last);
    _DEBUG_POINTER(_Dest);
    return (_Reverse_copy(_Unchecked(_First), _Unchecked(_Last),
        _Dest, _Is_checked(_Dest)));
    }

template<class _BidIt,
    class _OutTy,
    size_t _OutSize> inline
    _OutTy *reverse_copy(_BidIt _First, _BidIt _Last,
        _OutTy (&_Dest)[_OutSize])
    {   // copy reversing elements in [_First, _Last), array dest
    return (_Unchecked(
        _STD reverse_copy(_First, _Last,
            _Array_iterator<_OutTy, _OutSize>(_Dest))));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the function. The compiler is merely (helpfully) informing you that the code is unsafe because pointers cannot be checked in debug mode and so any overflow would result in undefined behavior.

VC++ provides a function specifically for this purpose called `stdext::make_checked_array_iterator`. Use it like so:

```
std::reverse_copy(encodedInteger, encodedInteger+byteCount, 
     stdext::make_checked_array_iterator(block.begin(), block.size()));
```

Comment: Thanks. Which overload is that? Is it the one with `_Array_iterator<_OutTy, _OutSize>`? For completeness, I don't claim a destination buffer size is a problem. I'm glad that Microsoft embraces safer coding practices.